# Printing output by looping through each item not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a table that stores definitions of various terms of our stores like store_name, store_location and others. Given below is the view of how our table looks like:

```
store_name,store_location,store_workinghours
store_a,madison_square,9am-9pm
```

I am trying to print this such that I have each definition to the right of each term as shown below:

```
store_name,store_a
store_location,madison_square
store_workinghours,9am-9pm
```

I am trying to do this as below:

```
row = 1
col = 1

for values in table:
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        worksheet.write(current_col, idx, value, number_format)
    current_col += 1
```

I however see the above logic prints the data as well

```
store_name
store_a,madison_square
```

Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong with the above. Thanks

Update :

```
cursor.execute('select {} from table'.format(', '.join(str(label) for label in label_names)))
table = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: What is `table` here? A dictionary?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, it is the output of a SQL query that has all of these definitions.. I have updated my initial post with this remark on table and how it's generated.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output of `type(table)`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, its <class 'list'>